# How to implement recvmsg() with asyncio?

Tags: unix, python-3.5, python-asyncio

Since `recvmsg()` is missing in `asyncio` module, I've tried to reimplement it in exactly the same way as `BaseEventLoop.sock_recv()` is implemented:

```
import asyncio, socket


def _sock_recvmsg(loop, fut, registered, sock, bufsize, ancbufsize):
    self = loop
    fd = sock.fileno()
    if registered: self.remove_reader(fd)
    if fut.cancelled(): return
    try: data = sock.recvmsg(bufsize, ancbufsize)
    except (BlockingIOError, InterruptedError): self.add_reader(fd, self._sock_recvmsg, fut, True, sock, bufsize, ancbufsize)
    except Exception as exc: fut.set_exception(exc)
    else: fut.set_result(data)


def sock_recvmsg(loop, sock, bufsize, ancbufsize=0):
    self = loop
    if self._debug and sock.gettimeout() != 0: raise ValueError('the socket must be non-blocking')
    fut = asyncio.futures.Future(loop=self)
    self._sock_recvmsg(fut, False, sock, bufsize, ancbufsize)
    return fut


asyncio.unix_events._UnixSelectorEventLoop._sock_recvmsg = _sock_recvmsg
asyncio.unix_events._UnixSelectorEventLoop.sock_recvmsg = sock_recvmsg
```

But this trivial test fails, only the first value is received and test hangs after that:

```
async def produce():
    for i in range(5):
        end_out.sendmsg([bytes([i])])
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

    end_out.close()

async def consume():
    while True:
        v, a, b, c = await asyncio.get_event_loop().sock_recvmsg(end_in, 1)
        if v == b'': return
        print(v)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    end_in, end_out = socket.socketpair()
    asyncio.ensure_future(produce())
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(consume())
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Thanks for this gem.

Comment: https://discuss.python.org/t/expanding-asyncio-support-for-socket-apis/19277/9 has some discussion about this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`recvmsg()`-related code is correct, but I've missed

```
end_in.setblocking(0)
end_out.setblocking(0)
```

That is so stupid so I'm considering deletion of that question.

Comment: This was actually quite a time saver for me since I can now pretty much copy-paste your implementation ;)